# How to display ChoiceSet horizontally - Adaptivecards

Tags: adaptive-cards

Is there any way to make ChoiceSet to display horizontally(one option next to another), rather than stacking them on top of each other like in the [schema example of ChoiceSet](http://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Input.ChoiceSet.html)?

I am using the BotFramework-WebChat for the moment, and I am just wondering whether the only option to do that is to use CSS?

Answer (score 0):

That is not currently supported in the property set of the ChoiceSet element

http://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Input.ChoiceSet.html

You should request this as a feature on the GitHub site:

https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues